# Convert a column of integers in pandas dataframe to month with leading zeros

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to change the Month and Day column in the Python pandas dataframe from integer to strings with leading zeros.

What I want is here: the input is here as a pandas dataframe:

```py
Year Month  Day
2018     1    1
2018     1   12
2018     1   18
2018     2    4
2018     2    1
2018     2    2
2018     2   12
2018     3   30
```

I want to make them like this:

```py
Year Month  Day
2018    01   01
2018    01   12
2018    01   18
2018    02   04
2018    02   01
2018    02   02
2018    02   12
2018    03   30
```

My method is pretty dumb, and it is very slow.

```py
def Import():
    df = pd.read_csv('Transaction_data.csv',index_col=0)
    n = len(df)
    for i in range(n):
        temp = df['Year'].loc[i]
        df['Year'].loc[i] = str(temp)

    for i in range(n):
        temp = df['Month'].loc[i]
        if temp<10:
            df['Month'].loc[i] = '0'+str(temp)
        else:
            df['Month'].loc[i] = str(temp)

    for i in range(n):
        temp = df['Day'].loc[i]
        if temp<10:
            df['Day'].loc[i] = '0'+str(temp)
        else:
            df['Day'].loc[i] = str(temp)
    return df
```

Also

```py
pd.to_datetime(df['Month'],format='%d')
```

won't help since to_datetime only has month as integers [1,12]

Comment: Consider keeping one column: `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])`. All of that information is then easily accessible with the [`.dt` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#accessors) in addition to a host of other properties that will make your life easier.

Answer (score 5):

> I want to change the Month and Day column in the Python pandas dataframe from integer to strings with leading zeros.

Use [`series.str.zfill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
df[['Month','Day']]=df[['Month','Day']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.zfill(2))
print(df)
```

---

```
   Year Month Day
0  2018    01  01
1  2018    01  12
2  2018    01  18
3  2018    02  04
4  2018    02  01
5  2018    02  02
6  2018    02  12
7  2018    03  30
```

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you wish to have a string value so you can use a simple lambda. On the Day example you should have:

```
df['Day'].apply(lambda x: "0"+str(x) if x<10 else x)
```