# Python set value with loop and if

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have a date and time column which I set using pd.to_datetime but panda reads the date wrong when the first value is not a 0. Example is 5/08/2021 when it needs to be 05/08/2021. If the date is 10/08/2021 it reads it fine.

Can you please help with a python loop style code which looks at each date per row and if there is a / as the second value then add a 0 at the front of the date. If the second value is not a / then skip to the next row.

I want to use this code when the column is in object format. Then when the column is edited I will do the pd.to_datetime.

Thanks if you can help.

Comment: your question is unclear please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56912864/convert-a-column-of-integers-in-pandas-dataframe-to-month-with-leading-zeros). May be this is what you want

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> pd.to_datetime('5/08/2021', format='%d/%m/%Y')
Timestamp('2021-08-05 00:00:00')
```

No need to any loop. This works fine. You just need to define the time format as '%d/%m/%Y'.